# htaccess URL rewrite with "special character" "&"

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, plugins, typo3

I implemeted a TYPO3 plugin and need to restrict direct download requests to a folder. I want to redirect each pdf download to my Plugin. Here i get problems with the URL

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/uploads/tx_srcproducts/(.*)\.pdf$ /index.php?id=1389&tx_srcproducts_srcproducts
```

Direct dowmloads comes like that:

http://mypage.com/uploads/tx_srcproducts/26-215_FR10_Catalogue-Systeme_Controls.pdf

Now the result trough htaccess is:

http://mypage.com//index.php?id=1389/uploads/tx_srcproducts/26-215_FR10_Catalogue-Systeme_Controls.pdftx_srcproducts_srcproducts

But i would need it like that:

http://mypage.com/index.php?id=1389&tx_srcproducts_srcproducts[file]=26-215_FR10_Catalogue-Systeme_Controls.pdf

so there is a problem with the "&".

Hope someone can help me with that htaccess stuff  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using captured `$1`.

Try this mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^uploads/tx_srcproducts/(.+?\.pdf)$ /index.php?id=1389&tx_srcproducts_srcproducts[file]=$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Hi thx for that. It´s very close now. Just the "[file]" is missing...

http://mypage.com/index.php?id=1389&tx_srcproducts_srcproducts[file]=26-215_FR10_Catalogue-Systeme_Controls.pdf

if i add the [file] after the tx_srcproducts_srcproducts it shows %5bfile%5 instead of [file]

Comment: can we add the same for zip and ppt?